# React Native CLI Versions found: N/A error

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-studio

I'm sure I installed it properly but unfortunately I'm getting an error, can you help me? I tried installing different versions of Node.js but it gave the same error, I also tried it with different versions of devices in Android column, unfortunately it didn't work. My English is not very good, sorry if there is a mistake.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/napvY.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOmfQ.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhwBU.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myI3B.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UouVc.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM0tB.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MznMf.png)
I want to run a mobile device from within the android studio I installed on my computer in react-native.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.